# how to validate text properties in a given groupbox using c#code for ranorex tool,can some one help me out

Tags: c#-4.0, ranorex

I have tried validating text properties in group boxes with c# code but failed to develop a code for tool ,can some one help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Validate.Attribute()` method:

```
public static void Attribute(
    RepoItemInfo itemInfo,
    string name,
    Object value
)
```

Parameters:

`itemInfo (RepoItemInfo)`: 
The `RepoItemInfo` object for the repository item.

`name (String)`: 
The name of the attribute to validate.

`value (Object)`: 
The value of the attribute to match.

Some more methods can be found in the [Ranorex API documentation](http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/).

Example:

```
Validate.Attribute(repo.Explorer.StartInfo, "Text", "yourtext");
```

I hope that helps.